# Google maps with color/gradient overlay

Tags: dictionary, web, overlay

On google maps, on the website, is there a way to make it so that all land area is of a gradient color, and no names, text etc shows? so just a gradient color map, with nothing else.

Or is it better to use an image for such a case? The thing is, i need to show pins at specific countries, so idk if its simpler to use an image, and set each pin position separately, or to somehow use google maps, if its possible to set it to gradient color?

any ideas are welcome

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own style map, I suggest you check the documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/styling or https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/google/maps-apis/studio/styles

The second link takes you straight to the management console to create your map.